# Is it possible to programmatically generate a pyi file from an instantiated class (for autocomplete)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm creating a class from a dictionary like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can get Intellisense for this dynamically generated class. Most IDEs can read pyi files for this sort of thing.

I don't want to write out a pyi file manually though.

Is it possible to instantiate this class and programmatically write a pyi file to disk from it?

mypy has the stubgen tool, but I can't figure out if it's possible to use it this way.

Can I import stubgen from mypy and feed it `MyClass(<some dict>)` somehow?

Comment: Do the attributes of `MyClass` vary dynamically, or are they fixed and only populated from the dict out of convenience?

Comment: Why would you need this class at all? If it's just a straight dict copy, why not just... use that dict?

Comment: ... or a `types.SimpleNamespace` (for variable keys) or `dataclasses.DataClass` (for fixed ones)?

Comment: @Brian the dict my vary at run time but there is a default dict that is loaded that would be good enough for me. It's embedded in the code base and I'm wondering if I could call stubgen against it in setup.py or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static analysis programs like stubgen are the wrong tool for analysing a class populated dynamically, because they can't see the source code of your fully-formed class to give you the stub of the class. You have to do the stub generation at runtime by running the source code to populate your instance attributes first.

---

Let's say that you have a dynamically-populated class, as in your example,

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, dictionary: dict[str, object]) -> None:
        k: str
        v: object
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

and you pass in this dictionary to the constructor,

```py
import statistics

instance: MyClass = MyClass({"a": 1, "b": "my_string", "distribution": statistics.NormalDist(0.0, 1.0)})
```

and you want this as your output:

```py
import statistics

class MyClass:
    a: int
    b: str
    distribution: statistics.NormalDist

    def __init__(self, dictionary: dict[str, object]) -> None:
        ...
```

The easiest way to generate the output above is to hook into instance creation and initialisation, so you don't affect whatever `__new__` or `__init__` chained `super` calls which already exist on your class. This can be done via a metaclass's `__call__` method:

```py
class _PostInitialisationMeta(type):

    """
    Metaclass for classes subject to dynamic stub generation
    """

    def __call__(
        cls, dictionary: dict[str, object], *args: object, **kwargs: object
    ) -> object:

        """
        Override instance creation and initialisation. Generate a string representing
        the class's stub definition suitable for a `.pyi` file.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dictionary
            Mapping from instance attribute names to attribute values
        *args
        **kwargs
            Other positional and keyword arguments to the class's `__new__` and
            `__init__` methods

        Returns
        -------
        object
            Created instance
        """

        instance: object = super().__call__(dictionary, *args, **kwargs)
        <generate string here>
        return instance
```

You can then parse the class into an [abstract syntax tree](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), modify the tree by adding, removing, or transforming nodes, then unparse the transformed tree. Here's one possible implementation using the Python standard library's [`ast.NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor):

**Python 3.9+ only**

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import ast
import inspect
import typing as t


if t.TYPE_CHECKING:

    class _SupportsBodyStatements(t.Protocol):
        body: list[ast.stmt]


_CLASS_TO_STUB_SOURCE_DICT: t.Final[dict[type, str]] = {}


class _PostInitialisationMeta(type):

    """
    Metaclass for classes subject to dynamic stub generation
    """

    def __call__(
        cls, dictionary: dict[str, object], *args: object, **kwargs: object
    ) -> object:

        """
        Override instance creation and initialisation. The first time an instance of a
        class is created and initialised, cache a string representing the class's stub
        definition suitable for a `.pyi` file.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dictionary
            Mapping from instance attribute names to attribute values
        *args
        **kwargs
            Other positional and keyword arguments to the class's `__new__` and
            `__init__` methods

        Returns
        -------
        object
            Created instance
        """

        instance: object = super().__call__(dictionary, *args, **kwargs)
        _DynamicClassStubsGenerator.cache_stub_for_dynamic_class(cls, dictionary)
        return instance


def _remove_docstring(node: _SupportsBodyStatements, /) -> None:

    """
    Removes a docstring node if it exists in the given node's body
    """

    first_node: ast.stmt = node.body[0]
    if (
        isinstance(first_node, ast.Expr)
        and isinstance(first_node.value, ast.Constant)
        and (type(first_node.value.value) is str)
    ):
        node.body.pop(0)


def _replace_body_with_ellipsis(node: _SupportsBodyStatements, /) -> None:

    """
    Replaces the body of a given node with a single `...`
    """

    node.body[:] = [ast.Expr(ast.Constant(value=...))]


class _DynamicClassStubsGenerator(ast.NodeVisitor):

    """
    Generate and cache stubs for class instances whose instance variables are populated
    dynamically
    """

    @classmethod
    def cache_stub_for_dynamic_class(
        StubsGenerator, Class: type, dictionary: dict[str, object], /
    ) -> None:

        # Disallow stubs generation if the stub source is already generated
        try:
            _CLASS_TO_STUB_SOURCE_DICT[Class]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            return

        # Get class's source code
        src: str = inspect.getsource(Class)
        module_tree: ast.Module = ast.parse(src)

        class_statement: ast.stmt = module_tree.body[0]
        assert isinstance(class_statement, ast.ClassDef)

        # Strip unnecessary details from class body
        stubs_generator: _DynamicClassStubsGenerator = StubsGenerator()
        stubs_generator.visit(module_tree)

        # Adds the following:
        #  - annotated instance attributes on the class body
        #  - import statements for non-builtins
        # --------------------------------------------------
        added_import_nodes: list[ast.stmt] = []
        added_class_nodes: list[ast.stmt] = []
        k: str
        v: object
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            value_type: type = type(v)
            value_type_name: str = value_type.__qualname__
            value_type_module_name: str = value_type.__module__

            annotated_assignment_statement: ast.stmt = ast.parse(
                f"{k}: {value_type_name}"
            ).body[0]
            assert isinstance(annotated_assignment_statement, ast.AnnAssign)
            added_class_nodes.append(annotated_assignment_statement)
            if value_type_module_name != "builtins":
                annotation_expression: ast.expr = (
                    annotated_assignment_statement.annotation
                )
                assert isinstance(annotation_expression, ast.Name)
                annotation_expression.id = (
                    f"{value_type_module_name}.{annotation_expression.id}"
                )
                added_import_nodes.append(
                    ast.Import(names=[ast.alias(name=value_type_module_name)])
                )

        module_tree.body[:] = [*added_import_nodes, *module_tree.body]
        class_statement.body[:] = [*added_class_nodes, *class_statement.body]
        _CLASS_TO_STUB_SOURCE_DICT[Class] = ast.unparse(module_tree)

    def visit_ClassDef(self, node: ast.ClassDef) -> None:
        _remove_docstring(node)
        node.keywords = []  # Clear metaclass and other keywords in class definition
        self.generic_visit(node)

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node: ast.FunctionDef) -> None:
        _replace_body_with_ellipsis(node)

    def visit_AsyncFunctionDef(self, node: ast.AsyncFunctionDef) -> None:
        _replace_body_with_ellipsis(node)
```

You can then run your class as usual, and then inspect what's stored in the cache `_CLASS_TO_STUB_SOURCE_DICT`:

```
class MyClass(metaclass=_PostInitialisationMeta):
    def __init__(self, dictionary: dict[str, object]) -> None:
        k: str
        v: object
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

>>> MyClass({"a": 1, "b": "my_string", "distribution": statistics.NormalDist(0.0, 1.0)})
>>> src: str
>>> for src in _CLASS_TO_STUB_SOURCE_DICT.values():
...     print(src)
...
import statistics

class MyClass:
    a: int
    b: str
    distribution: statistics.NormalDist

    def __init__(self, dictionary: dict[str, object]) -> None:
        ...
```

---

In practice, `.pyi` files form the type interfaces on a *per-module* basis, so the implementation above isn't immediately usable as it is only for a class. You also have to do much more processing with other kinds of nodes in your `.pyi` module, decide what to do with unannotated nodes, repeated imports, etc., before writing the source to a `.pyi` file. This is where stubgen may come in handy - it can analyse the static parts of your module, and you can take that output and write an `ast.NodeTransformer` to transform that output into the classes you've generated dynamically.

Comment: I'm thinking because this is going to be a fairly simple dataclass with one or two methods I might just build the content manually considering how complex this would be. This is extremely helpful though!